# Network Policy not evaluated for forwarded authentications

Tags: active-directory, radius, nps

I'm having a problem with NPS connection policies in combination with forwarded RADIUS requests - the connection policy does not seem to be evaluated?

Our domain has several one-way trusts. I have a network policy stating that only members of a given (domain local) security group can connect. I then have several Connection Request Policies forwarding to NPS servers in the remote domains, with conditions on user name `DOMAIN-NAME\\.+`. The forwarding works fine, but it seems that the group membership part is not evaluated?

It works fine for users in the local `OPS` domain, but for all others simply having valid credentials is enough. I've tried setting the "Ignore user account dial-in properties" since it was suggested elsewhere, but it did not seem to make any difference.